# Stretching row over container but keeping other content inside container

Tags: css

I'm using Visual Composer with Wordpress and having trouble styling a row(div). I want to extend row to the left edge of the browser but keep my div that's inside on the same place.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

See the picture attached:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg7L2.png

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `::before` that is `position: absolute` and set the row as `position: relative`, and then style the `::before` to suite your needs.